# Form query string using ajax and php

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am calling a ajax function on button click.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "javascript.php?orderid=CF450AA4",
            //data: "orderid=CF450AA4",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg, status) {
                alert("successful");
                console.log(msg);
            },
            error: function (msg, status) {
                console.log("failure");
                console.log(msg);
                alert("failure");
            }
        });
}
```

I have the javascipt.php file where the code is written for server side and is working fine.
I want to recode it. I want that when someone clicks on button the url change to index.php?orderid=CF450AA4 and result is delivered in the variable. How to do this

Answer (score 0):

i did it by doing..

`location.hash = 'url';`

Hope will work for you..

Comment: It will add the word `url` in the url followed by `#` like `www.abc.com#url` its is not the right answer

Comment: this is giving http://localhost/index.php#javascript.php?orderid=CF450AA4    i am looking something like this index.php?orderid=CF450AA4. i am ready to delete javascript.php file and write in index.php